How do You Convert a List of Strings into a Frozenset and Add it to a Set of Frozensets?
I have a variable with n words, separated by whitespaces. str.split() returns a list of these words, which is then converted to a tuple with tuple(), which is finally converted to a frozenset and added to the set of frozensets. For some reason this returns:
TypeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object is not subscriptable

my code:
set = set([])
str = 'a b c d'
set.add[frozenset(tuple(set.split()))]

problems already addressed :

tried to make a set of sets`
tried to make a frozenset out of lists
accidentally used .append instead of .add

(Btw this is my first question on stack overflow)

first, you should not name your vars with reserved names/built-ins. then, set.add is a function, use parens not brackets. and finally you don't need the tuple step.
my_set = set()
my_set.add(frozenset('a b c d'.split()))


To be clear, set and str are not reserved, which is why this is a recurring problem for new Python programmers. You're allowed to shadow the builtins. You just shouldn't.
